# What POSIX system interfaces depend on /bin/sh?

Tags: c, unix, posix, sh

The POSIX system interfaces

- [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html)
- [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html)

both use `/bin/sh` to execute external programs. Are there any other POSIX functions that, if I use them in my application, will introduce a dependency on `/bin/sh`?

Comment: `popen` is not a standard C function.

Comment: Low level functions like open close read write use routines provided by the Un*x kernel, however C executables work perfectly on DOS and Windows™ , so they also provide these routines.

Comment: @nwellnhof He didn't say standard C. The question is tagged Unix.

Comment: [What is your (actual) question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Those two are the only ones that come to my mind.

Comment: _[HERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)_ is a reference that seems to support Barmer's comment.

Comment: @Barmar The original unedited question said "standard C".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list includes at least:

- `popen()`
- `system()`
- `execlp()` and `execvp()`

  > In the cases where the other members of the exec family of functions would fail and set errno to `[ENOEXEC]`, the `execlp()` and `execvp()` functions shall execute a command interpreter and the environment of the executed command shall be as if the process invoked the `sh` utility
- `wordexp()` (possibly)

  > While `wordexp()` could be implemented entirely as a library routine, it is expected that most implementations run a shell in a subprocess to do the expansion.

Quotes are from [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Comment: It looks like `posix_spawn()` also uses `/bin/sh` if the new process image file is not an executable.

Comment: @rphv: that's possible but it's not mentioned in Posix nor in the manpages for Linux or FreeBSD. Did you try the experiment? If so, on what system? (Using /bin/sh is not the same as interpreting a shebang line. The shebang can be handled without a shell since it does not do argument parsing.)

Comment: I came to that conclusion by grepping the glibc repository. In sysdeps/posix/spawni.c there's the following comment along with a call to `__execve` using the path `/bin/sh`: "The file is accessible but it is not an executable file.  Invoke the shell to interpret it as a script."

Comment: @rphv: If you look closer at glibc, you will see that the code you found only executes in compatibility mode for versions 2.2 through 2.15 of glibc. There is a note in the Changelog dated 2011-09-05 which references [bug  #13134](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13134).

Comment: I agree with your assessment. Thank you for taking a look.